# What is the best way to handle parametric circuits in Qiskit?

Tags: qiskit, programming, circuit-construction, vqe

What is the best way to handle parametric circuits in Qiskit? When I create a variational form like `TwoLocal` and then do `var_form.parameters` it returns a set but that is an unordered structure so I fear that it will give me different results upon different calls.

Here is what I have:

```
var_form = TwoLocal(num_qubits=4,
                       rotation_blocks=["ry","rx"],
                       entanglement_blocks=["cx"],
                       entanglement="full",
                       reps=1,
                       skip_final_rotation_layer=False,
                       insert_barriers=True)

parameters=np.random.random(var_form.num_parameters)
param_dict={}
for i in range(var_form.num_parameters):
    param_dict[list(var_form.parameters)[i]]=parameters[i]
```

Here is what I want:

```
def get_var_form(parameters):
    """parameters is a list like [0,1,2,3,4....]"""
    
    ## 
    # DO MAGIC HERE 
    var_form = TwoLocal(num_qubits=4,
                       rotation_blocks=["ry","rx"],
                       entanglement_blocks=["cx"],
                       entanglement="full",
                       reps=1,
                       skip_final_rotation_layer=False,
                       insert_barriers=True)
    
    #I want to insert parameters----->var_form
    ##
    
    return var_form #with given parameters
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with:

```
param_dict={}
for i in range(var_form.num_parameters):
    param_dict[list(var_form.ordered_parameters)[i]]=parameters[i]

ansatz=var_form.bind_parameters(param_dict)
```

maybe its not the best way, but it works...

Comment: Seems to match the approach here: https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials/circuits_advanced/1_advanced_circuits.html#Parameterized-circuits